# Display show more in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

By default each section should show maximum three cells. If any cell contains more than three cells, it should display 'show more' option.If show more is tapped I want to display the rest of the cells in that particular section. Two days I spent, nothing worked out.Segments at the top of the table. Depend on segment selected, tableview load the cells. This code for each segment each section varies, so the func `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` becomes big seriously very big. I roughly added code. This code is what i have tried.

```
if segmentName == .Feature || segmentName == .Services
    {
        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            if boolShowFullFeature[indexPath.section] == false
            {
                if indexPath.row == showCells
                {
                    return createShowMoreCell(indexPath.section)
                }
                else
                {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchListViewCell
                    var firstTitle = "", secondTitle = "", thirdTitle = "", recomendValue = "", starValue = ""

                    (firstTitle, secondTitle, thirdTitle, recomendValue, starValue) = model.foodValue[indexPath.row]
                    cell.configureCell(firstTitle, secondTitle: secondTitle, thirdTitle: thirdTitle, recomendValue: recomendValue, starValue: starValue)
                    return cell
```

Comment: That's some interesting information. Do you also have a question?

Comment: @Antony What have you tried? Anything worked? What didn't?

Comment: @dasdom. Nice way to notify me.. :-)

Comment: @kostek I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

i had actually done this before. here is sample code:

```
var objects = [["1","2","3"],["q","w","e","r","t","y"],["z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]]
var sec = ["sec a","sec b","sec c"]
var showallSec = 0

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sec.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let items = objects[section].count

    if items > 3{
        if section == showallSec-1{
            return items
        }
        return 4
        }
    return items
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let object = objects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = object
    if(indexPath.section != showallSec-1){
    if(indexPath.row == 3){
        cell.textLabel!.text = "show more"
        }}
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sec[section]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row == 3){
        showallSec = indexPath.section + 1  
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```